# How do I capture third party requests using mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

I have a local express app running on `http://localhost:3000`. My app is using a third party API service, and I'm hoping I can use mitmproxy to see the third party API service's underlying requests (eg when I make a POST to `http://localhost:3000/activate`, I want to see exactly what API calls the third party service is making under the hood to complete my request).

I got this far:

Using `mitmdump -R http://localhost:3000 -p 8080` to view requests. The pf.conf file looks like this: `rdr on en0 inet proto tcp to any port 3000 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080`.

I chatted with someone on Slack, and was told to run another mitmproxy in transparent mode to see the underlying requests.

I tried to do that by setting my pf.conf file of the 2nd mitmproxy instance to this:

```
rdr on en0 inet proto tcp to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9090
rdr on en0 inet proto tcp to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9090
```

To run this 2nd instance, I used this: `mitmproxy -T -p 3128 --host`. Because port 8080 was already taken, I entered another random one.

This 2nd instance shows no activity when I make requests on `http://localhost:8080`, even when my intercept filter is ~q.

I'm completely new to this, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple -- any ideas?

Comment: Is the third party sending requests to the express app or is your app sending requests to the third party API?

Comment: My app is sending requests to the API service, and that API service is making internal API calls that I'm hoping I can see

Comment: The "API service" is your express app running on localhost:3000?

Comment: No, my express app is making calls to a bunch of API services, and I want to see what calls those API services are making behind the scenes to complete my requests. So for example, in a route I might POST to a certain external endpoint and get a response, but I'd like to see what further endpoints are being hit that get me that response.. is there a way to do that?

Comment: If those API services are remote (i.e. not on your machine), I don't see a way how you could see what they are doing internally. Sorry.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks anyway!